# Why console shows "scrollIntoView() is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner. Just wanna use scrollIntoView() on a button in JS. Console keeps showing
"Uncaught TypeError: eleOne.scrollIntoView is not a function".

What should I do?

```
let eleOne = jQuery('.ribe-insurance-tnc-footnote-container');
let eleTwo = jQuery('button.ribe-btn-primary.ribe-page-step-btn.ribe-continueBar-continueBtn');
eleTwo.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
eleOne.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your using jQuery to select the elements and then your using vanilla JS methods on them. jQuery objects wrap around DOM elements and provide a different API.

**jQuery Example**:

```
let eleOne = jQuery('.ribe-insurance-tnc-footnote-container');
let eleTwo = jQuery('button.ribe-btn-primary.ribe-page-step-btn.ribe-continueBar-continueBtn');

eleTwo.on('click', function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: eleOne.offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

**JavaScript Only example**:

```
let eleOne = document.querySelector('.ribe-insurance-tnc-footnote-container');
let eleTwo = document.querySelector('button.ribe-btn-primary.ribe-page-step-btn.ribe-continueBar-continueBtn');

eleTwo.addEventListener('click', function() {
    eleOne.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

**AND if you do want to combine it, heres the fix**: Access the first DOM element in the jQuery object using `[0]`

```
let eleOne = jQuery('.ribe-insurance-tnc-footnote-container');
let eleTwo = jQuery('button.ribe-btn-primary.ribe-page-step-btn.ribe-continueBar-continueBtn');

eleTwo.on('click', function() {
    eleOne[0].scrollIntoView(true); 
});
```